# How to save my query (formula) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a default table like this

```
+--+----------+--------+------+
|Id|class_name|class_id|medals|
+--+----------+--------+------+
|1 |7IPA1     |7       |3     |
|2 |7IPA2     |7       |2     |
|3 |7IPA3     |7       |5     |
|4 |8IPA1     |8       |1     |
|5 |8IPA2     |8       |7     |
|6 |8IPA3     |8       |3     |
+--+----------+--------+------+
```

which will be executed by

```
UPDATE MYTABLE 
SET CLASS_ID = SUBSTRING(CLASS_NAME,1,4)


+--+----------+--------+------+
|Id|class_name|class_id|medals|
+--+----------+--------+------+
|1 |7IPA1     |7IPA    |3     |
|2 |7IPA2     |7IPA    |2     |
|3 |7IPA3     |7IPA    |5     |
|4 |8IPA1     |8IPA    |1     |
|5 |8IPA2     |8IPA    |7     |
|6 |8IPA3     |8IPA    |3     |
+--+----------+--------+------+
```

How to save this query? So that when I insert new data, this query is automatically executed

I'm use sql server management studio 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can used the tigger  like below

```
create trigger trigger_class_id on MYTABLE 
After 
  insert
as 
UPDATE 
  MYTABLE 
SET 
  CLASS_ID = SUBSTRING(CLASS_NAME, 1, 4) WHERE ID=inserted.ID
```

Comment: Thanks @zpc i have tried that script, but when i import new data to MYTABLE, data on CLASS_ID no replace by 4 first character from CLASS_NAME

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do this as an update.  Instead, you want to have a *computed column*.

```
alter table mytable add class_id as (left(class_name, 4));
```

Of course, you'll want to be sure that the column name (`class_id`) is not already in the table before executing this command.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use tigger or  add this query along with insert Query.
 then your query would be.

```
Insert into MYTABLE (class_name,class_id,medals) values('','','')
UPDATE MYTABLE 
SET CLASS_ID = SUBSTRING(CLASS_NAME,1,4)
```